# A property extending convexity

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Recently, I was trying to prove the simply connectedness of some set $Σ$, finally I've found that for any two points in $Σ$ there is a path in Σ joining them consisting of the union of two segments.
This looks a bit like convexity, so I'm wondering if this property is already known under some designation or if it has other topological consequences and interpretations.
Thank you !

Comment: A disk in the plane with one point removed satisfies the condition that any two points can be connected by a path consisting of two straight segments. But it is not simply commented.

Comment: Yes you're right. Have you already met this property ? @MartinR

Comment: No, I don't think so.